# How are semisimple/completely reducible representations defined?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Wikiepdia says that "a semisimple representation (also called a completely reducible representation) is a linear representation of a group or an algebra that is a direct sum of simple representations". However, I have not seen a direct sum of representations defined at any point. I have however seen a direct sum of vector spaces defined. I am therefore wondering if the definition actually means something like the following:

> Let $T: G \to GL(V)$ be a representation of some group $G$ on a vector space $V$. If there exist subspaces $V_i$ such that $V$ is a direct sum thereof ($V = \bigoplus_i V_i$) and such that each $V_i$ is $G$-invariant and irreducible  itself then we say that $T$ is completely reducible (into the subrepresentations induced by each of these $G$-invariant subspaces).

That is, I am trying to formalize the notion of a direct sum of representations and, ostensibly, that involves some connection to the direct sum of underlying vector subspaces.

Comment: Direct sum of representations of course refers to those of the same group. Your elaboration seems okay.